# JOIN - showing missing rows but attaching them to specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Two tables

```
MEDIA_APPROVALS
[media_id] [firm_id] [approval_status]

FIRM_LIST
[firm_id] [firm_code]
```

End goal is to show what media is NOT approved by what firm.

By default, all media listed in the MEDIA_APPROVALS table is NOT approved by the firms listed in the FIRM_LIST table. So in order for media to be approved, the row must contain a firm_id with approval_status=1.

If a media piece is in the MEDIA_APPROVALS table & the row contains a firm_id and approval_status=0, that's easy - it's NOT approved.

Where it gets tricky to me is: if there is a MISSING ROW in the MEDIA_APPROVALS table for a media_id/firm_id connection, then that media_id is NOT approved for that firm.

Ultimately I want to arrive at this:

```
MEDIA_APPROVALS
100   1   1
100   2   1
101   1   0
101   2   0
101   3   1
102   1   1

FIRM_LIST
1   AA
2   BB
3   CC

QUERY OUTPUT
100   CC   0
101   AA   0
101   BB   0
102   BB   0
102   CC   0
```

I am a PHP/web programmer and NOT a db admin. The help is HUGELY appreciated!

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql-server? Those tags refer to two very different database engines.

Comment: I ask, because if you're using Mysql, it won't accept the CTE from my answer, and I'll have to re-write it a bit for you to use an inline view instead.

Comment: Is there a media table?  That would simplify things a lot if there was.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need every possible combination of Media and Firm? Ooh, that's a CROSS JOIN. We don't get to do those very often:

```
WITH MediaFirms As (
    SELECT m_id.media_id, f_id.firm_id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT media_id FROM MEDIA_APPROVALS) m_id
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT firm_ID FROM FIRM_LIST) f_id
)
SELECT mf.media_id, mf.firm_id, coalesce(ma.approval_status, 0) "approval_status"
FROM MediaFirms mf
LEFT JOIN MEDIA_APPROVALS ma ON ma.media_id = mf.media_id AND ma.firm_id = mf.firm_id
WHERE coalesce(ma.approval_status,0) <> 1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that OP had `CROSS JOIN` his mind. To me it sounds more like a one OUTER JOIN where both NULLs and zeroes will be treated as *not approved*.

Comment: @PM77-1 Based on his description, OUTER JOIN alone won't do it, because not every firm_id he wants has a match in the media table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Very close but my final output only has to have records where approval_status!=1. At what part would I include that?

Comment: @joelcoehoorn I got it - WITH MediaFirms As (
    SELECT m_id.media_id, f_id.firm_id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT media_id FROM Media_Pre_Approval_Firm) m_id
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT firm_id FROM Pre_Approval_Firm) f_id
)
SELECT mf.media_id, mf.firm_id, coalesce(ma.firm_approval_status_id, 0) as firm_approval
FROM MediaFirms mf
LEFT JOIN Media_Pre_Approval_Firm ma ON ma.media_id = mf.media_id AND ma.firm_id = mf.firm_id WHERE ma.firm_approval_status_id IS NULL OR ma.firm_approval_status_id!=1